# Why does bacillus thuringiensis produce bt toxin?

Tags: evolution, microbiology, biotechnology, bacterial-toxins

Background : *B.thuringiensis* produces an inactive crystalline toxin during sporulation which when ingested by an insect, gets activated and causes pore formation in gut , subsequently leading to death of the insect.

Question : What is the  role of the toxin in bacteria's own metabolism ? Does it "unintentionally" kill the insects or is there an evolutionary advantage gained by the bacteria ?

Comment: Apparently the bacterium is an opportunistic pathogen. See [here](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-94-017-1429-7_3).